# AirPlay enabled speaker disappears from iTunes

Tags: airplay, itunes

I have the AirPlay enabled [B&W Zeppelin Air](http://www.bowers-wilkins.com/iPod_and_Computer_Speakers/iPod_and_Computer_Speakers/Zeppelin_Air/overview.html) all set up correctly on my local WiFi. However, quite often when waking my iMac from sleep it will have disappeared from the list of AirPlay devices in iTunes to stream to.

I am not sure what the problem is. The speaker still shows up on all my other iDevices, and in iTunes I still get my AppleTV in the list of devices. I also can ping the IP address of the speaker from the computer without a problem.

So far the only solution for me has been restarting the computer. Just restarting iTunes does not do the trick. Disabling and re-enabling my network interface (it is connected through cable) also seems to work. However I am looking for a more elegant or permanent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a common issue with the Zeppelin Air and upgrading your firmware should resolve the issue.

**How to Upgrade the Zeppelin Air Firmware**

You should check the firmware installed on your Zepplin Air. You can view the current firmware version on the screen of an attached iPhone and most iPods. Generally it can be found in the "About" section in the "Settings" in the iPod menu.

The latest firmware for your Zeppelin Air is available in the [support section](http://www.bowers-wilkins.co.uk/iPod_and_Computer_Speakers/iPod_and_Computer_Speakers/Zeppelin_Mini/Support.html) on the B&W website. Download the installer from their site and then follow the instructions found in the [manual](http://www.bowers-wilkins.co.uk/Downloads/Product/Manual/ENG_FP29059_Zeppelin-Mini_manual.pdf) to upgrade the software via a USB 'B' cable.

[image]

**Didn't help?**

If this does not help can you please provide the following additional pieces of information: the firmware version of the software installed on your Zeppelin Air, the version of Mac OS running on your machine(s), the version of iTunes you are currently using.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. There was indeed an updated firmware available and I just installed it. I'll try this out for a while and will accept your answer if the problem does not reappear.